# HTML/HTA set image position to VBScript variable

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

So I basically want to make a button that changes an image's, let's say, x position to a VBScript variable in HTML. This is an HTA btw, dunno if it actually changes anything.

```
<script language = "vbscript">
    Position = 50
</script>

<body>
    <img src = "Something.jpeg" style = "position:relative; top:100px; left:(Position)px;">
</body>
```

Sorry if I worded this badly...

Comment: It would help to edit your question following [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I think I figured out what you're asking. Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to change an image's position in an HTA based on user input, then the following code example demonstrates how to do that. Note that no button is required. As soon as new values are entered (and you tab to another element or click in the blank space) the  image moves.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script language = "vbscript">
  Sub window_onLoad
    xPos.value = 50
    yPos.value = 100
    SetPosition
  End Sub
  Sub SetPosition
    Pic1.style.top = yPos.value & "px"
    Pic1.style.left = xPos.value & "px"
  End Sub
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type=text id=xPos size=3 OnChange=SetPosition()>
  <input type=text id=yPos size=3 OnChange=SetPosition()><br><br>
  <img src="Something.jpeg" id=Pic1 style="position:relative">
</body>
</html>
```